# How do you load js and style resources from CDN with local fallback using wp_enqueue_scripts?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style, cdn

I had a hard time finding the correct way to do this. I want to load the CDN resources here: http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/ but use `wp_enqueue_scripts` and have local fallback.

This is the method I am using for local fall back now directly in header.php:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
```

I want something like this for all resources but also using wp_enqueue_scripts. I successful switched the enqueue Jquery using this method but this does not provide a fallback:

```
/** Jquery **/
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
wp_register_script( 'jquery', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5./jquery.min.js','', 'latest', true );
wp_enqueue_script('jquery','','',true);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Since 4.5 there is a function that lets you append inline js to an enqueued js file, it is called [wp_add_inline_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/).

Now, this function does not let you add any js code that has a `</script>` in it for security reasons. But when you look at the wp_add_inline_script source code, you can see that it is just a wrapper for a [wp_scripts()->add_inline_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_scripts/add_inline_script/) call with some added string parsing for malicious strings.

So, if you don't mind using this function directly without the added security layer of wp_add_inline_script which parses for security problems (just the `</script>` check for now, but might be more in the future) then you can do the following:

```
function _enqueue_my_scripts() {
  // the normal enqueue
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-cdn', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js' );
  // our custom code which will check for the existance of jQuery (in this case)
  wp_scripts()->add_inline_script( 'jquery-cdn',
    "window.jQuery || document.write('<script src=\"".get_template_directory_uri() ."/js/jQuery.js\">\\x3C/script>')", 'after');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', '_enqueue_my_scripts', 100);
```

Make sure to copy the wp_scripts() call exactly and only switch out the library test ('window.jQuery') for a test of the library you want to test and the '/js/jQuery.js' part for a path to your library, because the string gets parsed before output and only this way it gets printed in the correct way.

That code above will give you

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.Swiper || document.write('<script src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/wp-theme/js/jQuery.js">\x3C/script>')
</script>
```

in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

switch your function `wp_register_script` for immediate call of `wp_enqueue_script`.

Now, even though you are registering jquery and calling it through `wp_enqueue_script`, you are passing as an URL empty string, that is why you do not get it enqueued.